# Remove css selector propery without changing source css?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Say I want to override bootstrap table class from

```
.table {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
```

To:

```
.table {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
```

And I don't want to override `margin-bottom` to `0` because I want it to retain what ever its parent will define for it, how can I achieve this WITHOUT changing the actual bootstrap.css file?

Comment: I may have this misunderstood, but you could always create and link a custom.css file within the document **after** the bootstrap.css and apply changes within your new CSS file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.table {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: auto; or margin-bottom: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add another class to the element in the html and set the margin-bottom to zero.

Comment: "And I don't want to override margin-bottom to 0 because I want it to retain what ever its parent will define for it"

Comment: In that case you can set the margin-bottom to inherit